# NodeJS - Destroy all authentication sessions for a specific user id

Tags: node.js, express, redis, passport.js, express-session

I'm using a local passport strategy with express-session and the sessions are persisted in a redis database.

I would like to destroy all sessions for a specific user id ( for example, after user changes his password ), however, the session ids used for redis are not predictable, so I have to iterate all of the sessions and check the userId, which Passport saves deep in a JSON value in the cache entry.

I tried to modify the session id to something to the likes of `sess:user:1:random-uuid`, which would allow me to use a SCAN command with a regex.

However, the `genid` function of express-session is synchronous and it runs before the actual user is fetched and verified, so I don't really know the identity of the user by the time the `genid` function runs.

Is there a way to solve this without having to iterate through every redis key and compare the `userId` manually in code?

Comment: Yes, keep track of all sessions for a given user. For example by creating array entry in Redis.

Comment: Is this the preferred way of handling this?

Comment: Well, it will definitely be faster than SCAN or KEYS, which as far as I know both iterate over entire database. So potentially are very slow.